# TypeError: type() takes 1 or 3 arguments, Python

Tags: python, types

```
# addmember.py

def addmember(memberlist, newmembers):
    if type(newmembers) not in (type([]), type(())):
        newmembers = [newmembers]
    for m in newmembers:
        if m not in memberlist:
            memberlist.append(m)
    return memberlist
```

I make the python file above first and then load it at IDLE

```
 >>> members = ['a', 'b']
 >>> import addmember
 >>> addmember.addmember(members, 'c')
```

Then, the error alert like below:

```
if type(newmembers) not in (type([]), type(())):
TypeError: type() takes 1 or 3 arguments
```

I cannot understand the meaning of error.

Thanks in advance ~~ :)

Comment: Is this all of the relevant code? Is `type(` your code or that of python?

Comment: This either isn't your actual code, or isn't the actual error line. That line cannot possibly raise a `TypeError`, because `(type([]), type(()))` is `(list, tuple)`, and `type(newmembers)` can't fail. Please copy and paste the code and the traceback, instead of making us guess where you may have gotten something wrong in code that's sort of like what you posted.

Comment: The above code does not produce an error.

Comment: You are trying to create a method that accepts both a list of strings or one string. My recommendation is: Don't do that. Make one function called addmember that adds one member (a string) and one called addmembers that takes a list. That will save you much headache.

Comment: @LennartRegebro: That's really the best answer here. After all, this isn't difficult by accident, it's difficult because it's unpythonic and bug-prone, and the Python devs don't put effort into making bad code easier to write…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you want

```
if not isinstance(newmembers, (list, tuple)):
```

See [**`isinstance()`**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance).

[`type()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type) comparisons are generally a bad way to check for an object's compatibility because they ignore inheritance. For example:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict()
>>> type(d) == dict
False
>>> isinstance(d, dict)
True
```

Comment: +1. But even better, he probably doesn't want to instance-check for `(list, tuple)`, but for `collections.Sequence`—or, more simply, to EAFP it.

Comment: Strings are `Sequence`s, so, no he can't test for that.

Comment: @LennartRegebro Oh, didn't consider that myself... rollin' back.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to solve this problem is to not check for types at all.

The only reason you want to check here is so you can iterate over a single value if you don't get a list or tuple or something else you can iterate over, right? So why not just try to treat it as an iterable, and fall back if you can't?

```
def addmember(memberlist, newmembers):
    try:
        iterator = iter(newmembers)
    except TypeError:
        iterator = [newmembers]
    for m in iterator:
        if m not in memberlist:
            memberlist.append(m)
    return memberlist
```

If you do a lot of this, you can wrap it up in a function:

```
def iterscalar(iterable_or_scalar):
    try:
        return iter(iterable_or_scalar)
    except TypeError:
        return [iterable_or_scalar]
```

Now you just do this:

```
def addmember(memberlist, newmembers):
    for m in iterscalar(newmembers):
        if m not in memberlist:
            memberlist.append(m)
    return memberlist
```

---

Sometimes you want to treat strings as if they were scalars, even though they're actually iterable. To do that, you do need some kind of check.

But better to check "is an iterable, and isn't a string" than "is a list or tuple", because there are a lot more types of non-string iterables than there are strings.

And if you want something more general than a string check, which you usually want to check that `next(iter(newmembers))` is the same type as `newmembers`.

What you actually want depends on your use case, of course.

---

Of course if you just used the right data types, you wouldn't need this code at all. For example, if `memberlist` were a `set` instead of a `list`, you could just call `memberlist.update()`, and it would add any members that weren't already there and ignore the ones that were. (And if you need to preserve the order they were found in, use the simple `OrderedSet` recipe in the `collections` docs.) On top of being a whole lot simpler, it would also be a whole lot faster (because you don't need to keep searching the ever-growing list for each new member).

Comment: Beacuse `>>> iter('hepp')` doesn't fail.

Comment: @LennartRegebro: If you want to handle strings specially, that's easy too. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Sure it's easy. But then you check for types. ;-)

Comment: @LennartRegebro: Yes, but as I explain in the answer, it's still better to check iterable-that's-not-string, or iterable-that's-not-over-its-own-type or whatever's appropriate to your use case, than tuple-or-list.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `type()` to check what type an object is. Use [`isinstance()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
if not isinstance(newmembers, (list, tuple)):
    dostuff()
```

Your code shouldn't reproduce that error, you're only passing one argument to type()